# Watir: password field unfindable in Safari

Tags: watir, browser-automation, safariwatir

I'm brand new to Watir.  I'm using SafariWatir on a fully updated MBP Snow Leopard.

So far I've successfully used

```
goto, link, text_field, and button
```

but when I try to access a text_field with

```
type="password" name="pass" id="pass"
```

(as seen in Web Inspector) with

```
browser.text_field(:id, "pass") or
browser.text_field(:name, "pass")
```

I get

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate TextField
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very simple answer:

In Watir and FireWatir, a password field is called

```
text_field
```

In SafariWatir, a password field is called

```
password
```

So, to access a input of type=password, I needed to use

```
browser.password(:id, "pass")
```

or

```
browser.password(:name, "pass")
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: I have noticed that myself. Just to make it clear for others, to populate password in safariwatir: `browser.password(:id, "id").set "password"`

Answer (score 1):

Notes: I'm using mac 10.8,ruby 1.9.3;

The working sample is: `browser.password(:name,'password').set'yourpassword'`

There is no space between `set` and the value.